# $\int_X f(x)\,d\mu\,\,$ exists iff $\,\,\int_X \lvert \,f(x)\rvert\,d\mu\,\,$ does

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I know that, for a domain of finite measure $X$, provided that $f$ is measurable, each of the Lebesgue integrals$$\int_X f(x)d\mu\quad\text{ and }\quad\int_X |f(x)|d\mu$$exists if and only if the other one does.

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's that the property also holds if $X$ is not of finite measure, but is the sum $X=\bigcup_n X_n$ of countable measurable sets $X_n$ of finite measure $\mu(X_n)<\infty$ such that $X_1\subset X_2\subset...$. In this case the integral is [defined by](http://librarum.org/book/10022/159) $\int_Xf(x)d\mu=\lim_n\int_{X_n} f(x)d\mu$.

I have been able to prove that if $\int_X |f(x)|\,d\mu$ exists then $\int_X f(x)d\mu$ exists too, but I am not convinced that if $\int_X f(x)\,d\mu$ exists $\int_X |f(x)|\,d\mu$ also does.

Could anybody confirm that and, if it is true, explain how it can be proven? $\infty$ thanks!

EDIT: precised that $f$ must be measurable, thanks to KCd's comment.

Comment: It is false that existence of $\int_X |f(x)|\,d\mu$ implies existence of $\int_X f(x)\,d\mu$ in general. You *must* assume that $f$ is measurable and then there is an equivalence as you wrote. Without assuming $f$ is measurable, you could let $f = 1$ on a non-measurable subset $A$ of $X$ and $f = -1$ on the complement of $A$ in $X$. Then $|f(x)| = 1$ for all $x$, so $\int_X |f(x)|\,d\mu$ exists, but $\int_X f(x)\,d\mu$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've edited. Kolmogorov-Fomin's style, full of implicits, is infecting me... :-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral
$$
\int_X f\,d\mu,
$$
is by definition equal to
$$
\int_X f^+\,d\mu-\int_X f^-\,d\mu, \tag{1}
$$
where $f^+(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}$ and $f^-(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}$, and this definition makes sense, as a real number, if and only if $\int_X \lvert\,f\lvert\,d\mu<\infty$.

Why? If $\int_X \lvert\,f\lvert\,d\mu<\infty$, then $\int_X f^+\,d\mu,\int_X f^-\,d\mu<\infty$, and hence $(1)$ is definable. On the other hand, if $(1)$ is definable as a real number, then $\int_X f^+\,d\mu,\int_X f^-\,d\mu<\infty$ and as $\lvert\,f\lvert=f^-+f^+$, then $\int_X \lvert\,f\lvert\,d\mu<\infty$.

Comment: Very, very kind! Thank you so much!!! I find $f^+$ and $f^-$ very interesting: Kolmogorov-Fomins's uses a different (older fashioned?) approach and this one is very interesting for me! As to the complex case, I think we can consider $\int_X fd\mu=\int_X (\text{Re}f)^+d\mu-\int_X (\text{Re}f)^-d\mu+i\int_X (\text{Im}f)^+d\mu -i\int_X (\text{Im}f)^-d\mu$, and the fact that $|\text{Re}f|$ and $|\text{Im}f|$ are integrable proves that $|f|\leq|\text{Re}f|+|\text{Im}f|$ is.

Comment: If $\int_X|f|\,d\mu < \infty$ it is not automatically true that $\int_X f^+\,d\mu$ and $\int_Xf^-\,d\mu$ are finite, since perhaps $f = \pm 1$ (so $|f| = 1$) with $f = 1$ on a non-measurable subset of $X$ and $f = -1$ on the complement.