# $|f+g|^p$ Lebesgue-summable if $|f|^p$ and $|g|^p$ are

Tags: lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

I read that the Minkowski integral inequality, which I knew for Riemann integrals on $[a,b]$, holds for Lebesgue integrals in the following form:$$\forall p\geq 1\quad\quad\Bigg(\int_X |f+g|^p d\mu\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq \Bigg(\int_X |f|^p d\mu\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\Bigg(\int_X |g|^p d\mu\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$I have been able to prove it to myself except for a thing: how do we know that $|f+g|^p$ is summable if $|f|^p$ and $|g|^p$ are? Can anybody give a proof of that? I thank you all!!!

*EDIT*: removed sentence where I mistakenly wrote that if $|f|$ and $|g|$ are measurable then $|f+g|$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|f+g|^p \leq (|f| + |g|)^p \leq \left(2\max\{|f|,|g|\}\right)^p \leq 2^p \max\{|f|^p,|g|^p\} \leq 2^p(|f|^p+|g|^p)$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I would never had thought about it. Anyhow, I think that we must specify that $|f+g|$ is measurable (which would be if $f$ and $g$ were), because I'm not sure that $|f|$ and $|g|$'s measurability implies $|f+g|$'s, am I right? I've remembered this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979826/int-x-fx-d-mu-exists-iff-int-x-lvert-fx-rvert-d-mu-do

Comment: @DavideZena yeah, measurability is another question. Seems you wrote in the question that you understand how to show it is measurable

Comment: I think I was wrong, and have edited: if $|f|$ and $|g|$ are, $|f+g|$ isn't in general, as far as I now understand...

Comment: @DavideZena Yes, take a non measurable set $A$ and $B = R- A$, $f=1_{A} -1_B$, $g = 2\cdot1_A$, then $|f|$ and $|g|$ are measurable, but $|f+g|$ is not

Comment: $\infty$ thanks!!!

Comment: @DavideZena You are welcome. In fact, the function $|g|$ is my previous comment is not measurable, sorry I was in a hurry on my way home. We can take $g=1$ as a constant function...

Comment: No worry: thank you for all your help! I've now discovered that the functions in $L_p$ must be measurable by definition. My book, Kolmogorov-Fomin's, didn't say that :-s What a headache...